# How to use Cordova InAppBrowser into a HostedWebApps?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins

I have a website with 2 mobile-apps displayed with Cordova, and they works really great. But I have a problem :

**When an external link is triggered by the user, he go out of the application and don't have any possibility to come back on the App...** (except close and reopen).

I have installed [inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowserclose) according [to this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-GlVrTaeH0). Sounds very simple but not working...

Console :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Link (supposed to trigger InAppBrowser - not working) :

```
 <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes', 'toolbar=yes'); return false;">www.google.com</a>
```

And I just remembered, that my apps are displayed with a technique named [Hosted Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/run-web-app-in-cordova?view=toolsforcordova-2017). And maybe it's what InAppBrowser does not work : **we are already in a webbrowser ?!**

I will snip my config & js code bellow, [here's the tutorial of Microsoft who helped me on the App setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/run-web-app-in-cordova?view=toolsforcordova-2017).

**Goal : find a way to use InAppBrowser, because we have a lot of external links in our website.**

Any ideas please ?
Many thanks !

Here is the code :

**Index.js**

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        // Here, we redirect to the web site.
        var targetUrl = "https://www.website.test/";
        var bkpLink = document.getElementById("bkpLink");
        bkpLink.setAttribute("href", targetUrl);
        bkpLink.text = targetUrl;
        window.location.replace(targetUrl);
},
    // Note: This code is taken from the Cordova CLI template.
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

**App.js**

```
/*global app, $on */
(function () {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * Sets up a brand new Todo list.
   *
   * @param {string} name The name of your new to do list.
   */
  function Todo(name) {
    this.storage = new app.Store(name);
    this.model = new app.Model(this.storage);
    this.template = new app.Template();
    this.view = new app.View(this.template);
    this.controller = new app.Controller(this.model, this.view);
  }

  var todo = new Todo('todos-vanillajs');

  function setView() {
    todo.controller.setView(document.location.hash);
  }
  $on(window, 'load', setView);
  $on(window, 'hashchange', setView);

    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        var geotext = document.getElementById('geotext');
        geotext.textContent = 'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
          'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude;
    };

    var onError = function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    var button = document.getElementById('geo');
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
                          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
                          });


    function myOnDeviceReady() {
        if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
            navigator.notification.alert('An internet connection is required to continue');
        } else {
            window.location="https://www.website.test/";
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", myOnDeviceReady, false);

})();
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://www.website.test/ https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
  <title>mysite</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/todomvc-common/base.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/todomvc-app-css/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/overrides.css" />
</head>
<a id="bkpLink" href="https://www.website.test/" class="mysite_font">mysite</a>

  <div class="app">
      <img src="img/logo_gradient.png" style="width: 200px;">
      <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
          <p class="mysite_font event listening">Chargement de l'app...</p>
          <p class="mysite_font event received">Chargement...<br/>Merci de patienter quelques instants.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/todomvc-common/base.js"></script>
  <script src="js/helpers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/store.js"></script>
  <script src="js/model.js"></script>
  <script src="js/template.js"></script>
  <script src="js/view.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `postMessage()`. Load website.com in an `<iframe>` on the mobile app. When a link is clicked on website.com, JS on website.com sends a `postMessage()` to parent container, which would be mobile app, then have your mobile app trigger the correct action by listening to incoming `postMessage()` actions.

Comment: Hi @JM-AGMS, thanks for answer. We add the iFrame in the HTML, works good but some websites does not allow to be "inframed". Do you any solution to skirt this ? Thanks

Comment: Ask the website owner if you can iframe their site. Otherwise, the only other way I know how is to first load the website within a website that you control using server-side code, then iframe that. This also has its own limits.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Thank you so much for this answer. We tried the <iframe> but this is not working and we are basicly a search engine so we don't have contact with external referals. Do you know if there is a way to load the InAppBrowser into a html <div> ? It's maybe a solution

Answer (score 0):

From your question and follow ups, I'm assuming you are loading in yourwebsite.com into your mobile app, then on yourwebsite.com you want to open external links but keep otherwebsite.com within your app. If I'm understanding correctly, you can load yourwebsite.com in your mobile app and open external links with inAppBrowser by sending a `postMessage()` back to your mobile app with the external link.

First, loading in yourwebsite.com within an `<iframe>` on your mobile app:

```
<iframe src="https://www.yourwebsite.com">
```

On yourwebsite.com, when an external link is clicked (in my example, this anything with `. external_url` class and you'll most likely have to use `querySelectorAll` instead for multiple links), capture it with JS and send the href value back to the mobile app with `postMessage()`:

```
document.querySelector('.external_url').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // stops the user from loading this link
  var data = {'external_url': event.target.href};
  window.parent.postMessage(data, '*');
});
```

Back on your mobile app, you need to listen to incoming `postMesssage()`. And trigger inAppBrowser to open the external url that was passed back from yourwebsite.com.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (event.data.external_url) {
    window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(event.data.external_url, '_blank', 'location=no');
  }
}, true);
```

I have not tested this code, but it should get you pointed in the right direction with a few changes.

Comment: Hi JM, thanks for this, looks like verry smart. We will test it quickly and I will get back to you soon.