# How to open an URL with swift/cordova code triggered in HTML ? (by Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, cordova

I have a very sneaky problem. I'm using Cordova to embeded my web-app onto iOS app.

But we have external URL and with our technique, it's really painfull to open external URL. And Cordova plugins like InAppBrowser does not work (because our app is already use an inapp browser).

Goal : we want to open an external URL, from a HTML page, to the Safari navigator of the device.

Maybe with Javascript ? I thought about something like :

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

So maybe, we can add in `MainViewController` a command triggered by an HTML button who use Javascript to open the URL in Safari ?

Anyone have an idea ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

check for canOpenURL then open

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com"),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mebin, but it's pure swift code or JS ? (I've never touch Swift)

Comment: @Gdebrig This is pure swift. Are you looking for JS ?

Comment: @Merbin yes or/and no, i'm looking for a solution to open an html url on the Safari app, maybe with JS

Comment: @Gdebrig If you are using swift, the above should work fine. If you are looking for ios based webapp, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930001/force-link-to-open-in-mobile-safari-from-a-web-app-with-javascript for JS solution.

Comment: it's working but not for us : we are in a hosted web-app context so we need to open the Safari App, this just opens the url in our web-app

Comment: @Gdebrig Totally confused. what is the issue you facing and what yo need actually. could you please explain in detail.

Comment: yes sure, all explained here, in a Cordova-context : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304135/how-to-use-cordova-inappbrowser-into-a-hostedwebapps. We have a embeded web-app into a Cordova mobile app with some JS. But when we use external links, we have a issue. So we want to open Safari with the external URL and skirt our issue

Comment: @Gdebrig So when you click the URL, need to open Safari App. Is that correct ?
Javascript link action should redirect to some URL opened in Safari App. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes exactly ! We have a link/button with an URL on the HTML, when you click on it, Safari oppens with the URL

Comment: @Gdebrig are you using Cordova inappbrowser plugin ?

Comment: @Merbin, it's installed but not working. We have the same result than your first suggestion : the app open the external URL in the app and not with Safari (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930001/force-link-to-open-in-mobile-safari-from-a-web-app-with-javascript)

Comment: @Gdebrig Instead of `_blank` try `_system`. Call the method `cordova.InAppBrowser.open(encodeURI('https://www.google.com/'), "_system");` "_system" will open url in Safari on iOS

Comment: Thanks for. We added your snip but same result... `<a href="#" onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open(encodeURI('https://www.google.com/'), '_system');">lien</a>` I think it's because our web-app is already using the plugin...